# How to change the Index in DateFrame

Tags: python

open the csv, it contains 156 rows,but when load the csv,the first row become Index  and the values.When use the shape(),it showed (155L,).Why?

Comment: "why" what? Why 155L? Why "L"? Why the first row becomes index?

Comment: What it says ` df.shape[0] ` # gives number of row count and `df.shape[1]  # gives number of col count`

Comment: Try  `pd.read_csv(file, sep=' ', header=None, skiprows=1)`

Answer (score 1):

Because in [read_csv](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) first row is by default considered a header, so use:

```
pd.read_csv('my_file.csv', header=None)
```

Same goes for [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_excel.html#pandas.read_excel).

Comment: I added the 'header=None', the result is  same.

Answer (score 0):

Using `header=None` to explicitly states that the csv has no headers .

More to read from doc :

header : int or list of ints, default ‘infer’

Row number(s) to use as the column names, and the start of the data. Default behavior is to infer the column names: if no names are passed the behavior is identical to header=0 and column names are inferred from the first line of the file, if column names are passed explicitly then the behavior is identical to header=None. Explicitly pass header=0 to be able to replace existing names. The header can be a list of integers that specify row locations for a multi-index on the columns e.g. [0,1,3]. Intervening rows that are not specified will be skipped (e.g. 2 in this example is skipped). Note that this parameter ignores commented lines and empty lines if skip_blank_lines=True, so header=0 denotes the first line of data rather than the first line of the file.